# How to add custom attributes to standard HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to figure out how battlelog manages to start native application from inside Edge browser and found the following:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-intro-step="4" data-bind-action="matchmake-mp-role" data-track="playnow.matchmake.cqclassic.join" data-bind-intro="next" data-expansion="0" data-game="2048" data-platform="1" data-role="1" data-experience="1">
Play now
</button>
```

Please help me to understand how these attributes like data-bind-action, etc. have been added to button element as well as how are them being processed?

Comment: see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: If you want to use jquery see this https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: Custom attributes are just a way of storing *valid* data in a DOM element that has no inherent meaning or visual property.  How they are added and how they are used (or processed) can't be determined by just the HTML you are displaying.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `data-*` attribute are custom attributes; they're only use to store specific data that the web developer will use it in tater time in his code in JavaScript.

```
<button id="mybutton" class="btn btn-primary" data-intro-step="4" data-bind-action="matchmake-mp-role" data-track="playnow.matchmake.cqclassic.join" data-bind-intro="next" data-expansion="0" data-game="2048" data-platform="1" data-role="1" data-experience="1">
Play now
</button>
```

For example to access the `data-intro-step` value from jquery, developer may type `$('#mybutton').attr('data-intro-step')` or `$('#mybutton').data('data-intro-step')` and use it with somethiing in his code.

Usually they're add from php or a js framework like `jquery-plugins` or `angularjs`, and used in js. put you could also add them from js to use it later.

Comment: "The data-* attribute is not a standard" — [It is a standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)

Comment: "Usually they're add from php" — That's a very narrow view of the world.